# why must Qgis 2.0.1 Desktop access the internet when I start it?

Tags: qgis

and how do I stop it? I'm on dialup internet most of the time and I don't allow unnecessary internet traffic. This seems unnecessary. I can't see any good reason that Q must access the internet, but I can't find any way to turn it off in my settings. Maybe I overlooked it. It tries to run cmd.exe and if I block it from doing so Q won't start up. If I allow it, it hogs my already slow internet connection for a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

It is checking for updates for the plugins you have installed, and that come installed by default.  To turn off the check for the plugins go to the plugin manager, on the settings tab uncheck the "Check for updates on startup" box.

You can also block its internet access through your firewall settings.  See [this wiki](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Program-With-Windows-Firewall) for steps on how to accomplish this with the built in Windows firewall.

Comment: I figured it was checking for updates but could not find that setting (I'm fairly new to Q). When I did find it where you said to look, the box for plugin updates was not checked. So with that in mind, why is it insisting on internet access? I use Zone Alarm, and I already explained what happens if I do or don't allow it...Neither outcome is desirable. I just want it to stop trying.

Comment: Does it start up if you're not connected to the internet in general or only if you block it through the firewall?  QGIS will check for updates to the main program itself, but I think only if you force the check.  The only other place it might be going out looking for stuff is in Settings -> Options -> Network.  Clear the WMS search address and see if that helps.

Comment: Ironically it will start fine if I allow the process when I'm nmt online. But it will not start if I block it with the firewall when I'm online. I tried clearing the WMS address and nothing changed. Edit: it looks like even though it runs the same process, with the WMS address removed it does not make a connection. So maybe the problem is taken care of for now. I'll monitor it for a bit. Thanks